# Displaying an UIWebView and UITableView with different height

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiwebview, uiscrollview

On my project, I would like to display an `UIWebView` with a non-constant height and an `UITableView` with a non-constant height too.

So far, I tried to add an `UIWebView` and an `UITableView` in a `UIScrollView`, but it's not working.

Here's my current view (with just an UIWebView) [image]

I'm new on iOs development, so if you have any lead, thank you :)

Comment: So you want to have UIWebView on the top and table view below?

Comment: And if so, why don't you embed the `UIWebView` in a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: @freshking I remember now : I can't set my cell height depending on the size of my `UIWebView`

Comment: Sure you can... I suggest getting height like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123009/get-uiwebview-contents-height and then call reloadData on your tableview and in heightForRowAtIndexPath insert that height there.

Comment: Second approach is to have two different object in your view (webView and table view) and after getting height for your webview just change tableView's y-coordinate to be webview.frame.origin.y + webView.frame.size.height (or + computed height, depends on if you want to have webview with dynamic height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tableHeaderView`

Init the webView first

Init the tableView

set tableView's tableHeaderView

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = webView
```