# How to get correct height of view within tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom tableview cell with a UIWebView contained in it. The UIWebView content is large, so I have the cell expanding on tap. When the cell is collapsed I am fading the bottom of the cell to show the content is truncated.

To determine whether I should fade the cell content I am comparing the height of the cell with the height of the webview content within layoutSubviews().

This works the first time the cell is displayed.

When I tap to expand the fade out is removed. Good so far.

Now when I collapse the cell, the height reported in layoutSubviews() for the webview comes back correctly once, but it is immediately followed by a second call to layoutSubviews() which reports the height of the webview as the same size as the collapsed cell. This stops causes the cell fade that was just added to be removed.

I have inspected the cell with the view debugger and it reports the correct height for the webview.

How can I reliably get the height of the webview?

Here is my code from the custom cell:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

if (gradientLayer != nil) {
    [gradientLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    gradientLayer = nil;
}

// if cell height is less than web view height we must fade
if (self.frame.size.height < self.webView.bounds.size.height) {
    gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    NSObject* fadeColor = (NSObject*)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:.9].CGColor;
    NSObject* transparentColor = (NSObject*)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;

    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:transparentColor, fadeColor, nil];
    gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

    gradientLayer.bounds = self.bounds;
    gradientLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

    [self.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123009/get-uiwebview-contents-height

Comment: Using webView.scrollView.contentSize.height fixed it - thanks